# Can assertFieldOutput be tested on fields that are not Text Input based?

Tags: python, django, django-testing

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertFieldOutput

Going over documentation of `assertFieldOutput()`, it shows the ease of testing user text input via a dictionary. The key acts as the input into the form and the value acts the cleaned data that is returned or returns whatever error that is supplied to the field.

```
self.assertFieldOutput(
    EmailField, 
    {'a@a.com': 'a@a.com'}, # valid email
    {'aaa': ['Enter a valid email address.']} # invalid email; results in validation error
)
```

Given dictionary keys are hashable, is there no way to test form fields that are non text based such as select menus like *ModelMultipleChoiceField*?